# Formula to assign a suffix to a rank: IF 1 then "st", IF 2 then "nd", etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm comparing the position of a record to its position last year: `This year it is ranked 4th out of 50, in 2015 it was ranked 21st`. 
Is it possible to add the "st", "nd", "rd" and "th" to the rank automatically?

My data is in a table:

- COL A = Name of data point (Bob, Jane, Bill, Anne, etc.). This is a fixed column.
- COL B = latest year data,
- COL C = latest year rank,
- COL D = previous year data,
- COL E = previous year rank.

I'm fairly comfortable using IF formulas, but I'm not sure how to refer to the last digit in a cell and say:  IF "it's a 1 then 'st'", IF "it's a 2 then 'nd'", IF "it's a 3 then 'rd'", else 'th'.

Note that the rank can be a multi-digit number.  The letters are based on the last digit.  So rank of 31 is 31st.  The are also exceptions for the teens.  Ranks 11, 12 and 13 use "th".

Can this be done as a formula or does it need to be done by VBA?

Comment: It's not clear where this data comes from... Where is the "rank"?

Comment: @Dave I had tried some IF statements but I couldn't get it to recognise the last digit of 22 or 31.

Comment: @Dave The rank column is there but I may have to add another column to to include the suffix and then concatenate the two. It's just hard for it to recognise the last digit of 21 or 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes the "rank" is in cell B50"

```
=IF(B50=1,"st",IF(B50=2,"nd",IF(B50=3,"rd","th")))
```

The above will give you results like "st", "nd" etc

Although I suspect you'll want to also show the number, so use

```
=IF(B50=1,B50 & "st",IF(B50=2,B50 & "nd",IF(B50=3,B50 & "rd",B50 & "th")))
```

This will show results like "1st", "2nd" etc

Thanks to ejbytes comment, I didn't test > 10! The following snippet does it so you can have 22nd or 43rd etc

```
=IF(RIGHT(B50,1) = "1", B50&"st",IF(RIGHT(B50,1)="2",B50&"nd",IF(RIGHT(B50,1)="3",B50&"rd",B50&"th")))
```

Now we get into the issues of 11, 12 and 13, as well as 111, 112, 113 etc so we need to handle those!

```
=IF(RIGHT(B50,2)="11",B50 & "th",IF(RIGHT(B50,2)="12",B50&"th",IF(RIGHT(B50,2)="13",B50&"th",IF(RIGHT(B50,1)="1",B50&"st",IF(RIGHT(B50,1)="2",B50&"nd",IF(RIGHT(B50,1)="3",B50&"rd",B50&"th"))))))
```

Finally, we're left with 0... 10th, 50th, 100th, but we also have 0!

```
=IF(B50=0,0,IF(RIGHT(B50,2)="11",B50&"th",IF(RIGHT(B50,2)="12",B50&"th",IF(RIGHT(B50,2)="13",B50&"th",IF(RIGHT(B50,1)="1",B50&"st",IF(RIGHT(B50,1)="2",B50&"nd",IF(RIGHT(B50,1)="3",B50&"rd",B50&"th")))))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the second one a go, but I worry it might not recognise the 'last digit' of a two digit number. I may add another column to take the right most digit and then run your formula on that...

Comment: I added another column to extract the left most digit. Then I aimed your IF formula at that. I'll put the answer in below. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: This works fine and get them all. Nice logic. I'd even go further to say that you could substitute each cell, for example B50, with RIGHT(B50,1), which will always look the last digit in the number (e.g. 20th 151st 23rd 334th...)

Comment: And for 21? I added the above comment because this only works on numbers 1-9, all numbers greater than 9 are n-th.

Comment: @Dave I ended up using your last formula. It worked a treat for what I needed to do. Many thanks for helping with this issue. When I say helping, I actually mean solving. Thanks. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Working with @Dave IF formula I had to make some amendments to my sheet of data.

Recognising the left most digit meant I needed to add another 'helper' column.

- Column A is original rank number
- Column B is a new helper column =VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1)) This gives me the last digit.
- Column C has the formula

  ```
  =IF(A1=12,A1&"th",IF(A1=13,A1&"th",IF(B1=1,A1&"st",IF(B1=2,A1&"nd",IF(B1=3,A1&"rd",A1&"th")))))
  ```

I had to handle 12 and 13 specifically…because of English!

It works, but it might hurt the eyes.
Thanks

Comment: You also need an exception for 11.

Comment: If you add four spaces before the formula, it will become a code block, this will help with readability

Comment: =IF(AND(A1>10, A1<14), A1&"th",  IF(RIGHT(A1,1)=1,A1&"st", IF(RIGHT(A1,1)=2,A1&"nd", IF(RIGHT(A1,1)=3,A1&rd,A1&"th"))))

Comment: @fixer1234 Yep. That one as well.

Comment: @ejbytes thanks for this. I've sort of solved the problem, but I'll certainly copy this formula for an example of how to nest effectively.